# SELECTing monthly order amounts and item subtotals in a single query with two tables

Tags: sql

I have an Orders table in the form:

```
| id | service_fee_cents | grand_total_cents | created_at    |
|----|-------------------|-------------------|---------------|
| 1  | 1400              | 10000             | Jan 21 2018   |
| 2  | 1000              | 10000             | Feb 16 2018   |
| 3  | 500               | 10000             | March 21 2018 |
| 4  | 500               | 10000             | March 20 2018 |
```

And an Items table in the form

```
| id | order_id | title  | price_cents | quantity |
|----|----------|--------|-------------|----------|
| 1  | 1        | lorem  | 2000        | 2        |
| 2  | 1        | ipsum  | 2030        | 1        |
| 3  | 2        | pie    | 4000        | 4        |
| 4  | 3        | cheese | 6000        | 2        |
| 5  | 3        | burger | 7000        | 1        |
| 6  | 4        | custar | 1000        | 1        |
```

And I'm trying to run a SQL query to get a result in the form

```
| month     | total_service_fee | total_grand_total | total_subtotal |
|-----------|-------------------|-------------------|----------------|
|2017-11-01 |   42              |   1,610           | 610            |
|2017-12-01 |   30              |   19,912          | 1,912          |
|2018-01-01 |   179             |   1,413           | 413            |
|2018-02-01 |   165             |   2,910           | 910            |
|2018-03-01 |   1,403           |   10,727          | 1,727          |
```

I've managed to get the first three columns using this query:

```
SELECT
    date_trunc('month', created_at)::date AS month,
    SUM(service_fee_cents) / 100 AS total_service_fee,
    SUM(grand_total_cents) / 100 AS total_grand_total
FROM orders
GROUP BY month ORDER BY month
```

How do I get the last one? In the app, I get the sum via the following Ruby code:

```
order_subtotal = order.items.map{|item| item.price * item.quantity}.reduce(:+)
```

Which basically takes all the order's items, multiplies price by quantity and adds the results.

Comment: Is it just me, or does the sample data you give not add up at all?   I see only one order for february (ID 2) and thats 4 x 4000.   Your subtotal line suggests it should be 910?  If you're going to give sample data, please make sure it aligns with your expected results

Comment: @Twelfth My sample data is truncated because the actual data is hundreds of thousands of rows long.

Comment: would I be correct that for the example data you've given, an expected output for feb would be 4 * 4000?

Comment: Which database engine is this for?

Comment: @Twelfth yes you would :)

Comment: @GVIrish postgresql

Comment: I think your sample query is missing a join with the items table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be a good start:

```
SELECT Date_trunc('month', created_at) :: DATE AS month, 
       SUM(service_fee_cents) / 100            AS total_service_fee, 
       SUM(grand_total_cents) / 100            AS total_grand_total, 
       SUM(total_subtotal) / 100               AS total_subtotals 
FROM   orders o 
       join (SELECT order_id, 
                    SUM(price_cents * quantity) total_subtotal 
             FROM   items i 
             GROUP  BY order_id) i 
         ON o.id = i.order_id 
GROUP  BY month 
ORDER  BY month
```

Comment: Thank you Daniel, however, I get this error: `column "b.total_subtotal" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function LINE 4: ...UM(grand_total_cents) / 100 AS total_grand_total, total_subt...`

Comment: sorry add that into your group by - see updated answer - does that work as you are expecting?

Comment: you could also do sum(total_subtotal) as well (or max/min).  Daniel - your answers would benefit from a brief English explanation of what your answer addresses, just so the user knows what you did and can repeat themselves later on.  "Subquery to get total_subtotal and join back to main query" would suffice.  +1 regardless

Comment: While I test this out, @DanielMarcus I can't make 2 character edits to your answer, but you've written `orderid` instead of `order_id` in some parts.

Comment: So, the result now becomes:

month              | total_service_fee | total_grand_total | total_subtotal
2017-10-01 |                             |                             | 545
2017-10-01 |                             |                             | 699
2017-10-01      |             5              |       25                 | 717

Comment: basically, I get multiple rows of the same month.

Comment: don't group by subtotal.  use sum(total_subtotal) in select, get rid of it in group by

Comment: Perfect! Thank you Twelfth! :)

Comment: @DanielMarcus this works beautifully, can you write an explanation or post documentation on this? I'm unfamiliar with the brackets. #newb

Comment: Basically you are just calculating the total_subtotal  at the order level in your subquery and then joining it back to your order table on orderid

Answer (score 0):

You can get there by just joining the Orders table to the Items table and generating a SUM of subtotals by month.  This may however be a  somewhat expensive query to run if there are thousands of items in each order like you said.

```
SELECT
    date_trunc('month', created_at)::date AS month,
    SUM(service_fee_cents) / 100 AS total_service_fee,
    SUM(grand_total_cents) / 100 AS total_grand_total,
    SUM(price_cents * quantity) / 100 AS sub_total
FROM Orders o
JOIN Items i ON i.order_id = o.id
GROUP BY month ORDER BY month
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/555a2/1

Comment: Hey GVIrish, unfortunately, the numbers are all wrong. I'm not sure what went wrong, but they're much bigger, although their line chart follows the same shape, only the peaks are much higher and the valleys much lower.

Comment: Perhaps I took it too literally when you said subtotal = price * quantity.  Were you looking to actually have subtotal = (price_cents * quantity)/100 aggregrated over each month?

Comment: I am, but even with those adjustments, the results are still wrong :(

Comment: I added a SQL Fiddle to confirm the logic here.  If the sub_total is quantity * price_cents for a given month, then in the sample rows you gave January 2018 should be 60.30, February: 160, and March 200.  One potential issue is that I was not casting the cents columns to decimal before doing division so you can end up losing precision there.  How are you verifying the results with your data?